# How to retrieve a daily sales from a running total sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help. I have MySQL table structure like below.
Orders is not daily orders just total orders. Date is timestamp
I want to see trending sales by category in last 3 days. I want to find which product trending in their category

```html
id, product_id, cat_id, orders, date
5,  2345,       15,    120,    2018-06-18 00:00:00
6,  2345,       15,    123,    2018-06-19 00:00:00
1,  2345,       15,    137,    2018-06-22 00:00:00
2,  2345,       15,    140,    2018-06-23 00:00:00
7,  456,        55,    127,    2018-06-18 00:00:00
8,  456,        55,    136,    2018-06-19 00:00:00
3,  456,        55,    152,    2018-06-22 00:00:00
4,  456,        55,    176,    2018-06-23 00:00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  What is this supposed to mean:  "I want to find which product trending in their category"?

Answer (score 0):

You need casting as date, grouping for product_id and cat_id and descending ordering by order totals according to the word *trending* supposed by me :

```
select product_id, cat_id, count(orders)  as total_orders
  from mytable
 where cast(date as date) >= cast(sysdate()-3 as date)
 group by product_id, cat_id
 order by count(orders) desc;

 product_id cat_id  total_orders
       2345   15         1
        456   55         1
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8a3a/2)

Comment: Thanks Barbaros bey. Buraya yazdiktan sonra kafam calismaya basladi. hall etdim.

Comment: @TariyelValiyev Bir şey değil değerli dostum kolay gelsin :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem . Thanks

```
select a.product_id,a.cox-b.az sales from (
SELECT product_id,
        max(orders) AS cox
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        date > ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) group by product_id order by cox desc) a,

(SELECT product_id,
        orders AS az
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        date > ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) group by product_id) b 


       where a.product_id=b.product_id 
        group by a.product_id order by sales desc
```